# Show fullscreen ad every 5. app opening

Tags: ios, ads, revmob

I am using ads from RevMob in an app I am developing, what I am wondering is how I can show a fullscreen ad every 5. app opening. I can't figure out how to do this, and I didn't find anything about this on the web. Thanks for helping!

The current code I am using is in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

[RevMobAds session].parallaxMode = RevMobParallaxModeOff;
        [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Think of your users. I recently purged one of my more useful apps because they started doing this.

Comment: Instead of every 5x launched maybe once every day or so?

Comment: Agree with @rmaddy.  Ads are OK, but they should be shown at some minimally intrusive time, not at app launch.  Every 5 document saves, after a level is beat, etc.

Comment: You got a point @rmaddy , I hate when other developers uses to much and annoying ads in apps - so I don't think I will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults to store the amount of times the app has been opened, and increment it everytime in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Then do whatever you want to do whenever its been opened 5 times :]

Ex:

```
NSInteger timesLaunched = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"timeslaunched"]
timesLaunched++
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:timesLaunched forKey:@"timeslaunched];

if (timesLaunched % 5 == 0) {
  // Show Ads
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest just using `integerForKey:` and `setInteger:forKey:`.  Your code will be cleaner without the NSNumber conversions.

Comment: @AaronBrager Good comment, don't know why that slipped my mind :]